# MySQL Load Data Infile

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to import CSV file into MySQL database but I am getting an error.

This is my method for `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```
public int Import(string path)
{
   try
   {
      string cmd = "LOAD DATA INFILE " + path + " INTO TABLE zen_hardware.products FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

      int a = MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn.Connect(),cmd);

      return a;
   }
   catch
   {
      return -1;
   }
}
```

When I run the code my string cmd gets this:

```
"LOAD DATA INFILE c:\\users\\trabajo\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Zen Hardware\\Presentation\\Tarjetas de Video.csv INTO TABLE zen_hardware.products FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

And the error I get is this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'c:\users\trabajo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Zen
>   Hardware\Presentation'

I don't know what part of my cmd syntax is wrong.

Comment: The result command should look like this:

    "LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\users\\trabajo\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Zen Hardware\\Presentation\\Tarjetas de Video.csv' INTO TABLE zen_hardware.products FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you are using an address that have space, must use single quotation (') before and after address like this:

"LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\users\trabajo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Zen Hardware\Presentation\Tarjetas de Video.csv' INTO TABLE zen_hardware.products FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"

```
public int Import(string path)
{
   try
   {
      string cmd = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + path + "' INTO TABLE zen_hardware.products FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
      int a = MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn.Connect(),cmd);
      return a;
   }
   catch
   {
      return -1;
   }
}
```

Please see the MySQL Manual Page entitled [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).